# Evaluating the limit of the quotient of two infinite sums

Tags: limits

How can I evaluate this limit?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2k-1} }}_{=:a_n}$$

By WolframAlpha, the limit has to be 2 but how can I show this? I see it is monotonous increasing so when i could show $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n = 2$, it would be done. But I'm a bit stuck...

Comment: *Hint*: Cesaro-Stolz.

Comment: This is not a limit of a quotient of two infinite sums. If it were something like $$ \frac{\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n \cdots }{\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n \cdots } $$ then that would be a quotient of two infinite sums. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

note that the denominator can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac 1k - \frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1k$$
It becomes pretty easy after this: divide numerator and denominator by $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k$. This gives you the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac 12 + \frac{\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1} \frac 1k}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k}}= 2$$

Answer (score 2):

**Intuitive explanation:**

The ratio is

$$2\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac 1k}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac 1{k-\frac12}}$$ and for growing $k$, the term $\frac12$ becomes less and less significant. At the same time both series diverge, so that the initial terms do not matter.

---

By a more serious argument, you could bracket the sums by integration and obtain bounds of the form $\log n+c$. Then by squeezing

$$\frac{\log n+c_1}{\frac12\log n+c_2}<2<\frac{\log n+c_3}{\frac12\log n+c_4}.$$

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's rule has a discrete version, under certain conditions; it is usually known as the [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Enagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf). Here, we treat summation as integration (and conversely, taking differences as differentiation). The statement is usually something like this: if the sequence $\{ b_n \}$ is positive and $\sum b_n = \infty$ (i.e. divergent), then for any sequence $\{ a_n \}$ of reals such that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n/b_n = L$, we have

$$ \lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{\sum_{j \le n} a_j}{\sum_{j\le n} b_j} = L. $$

A pretty cool consequence of this is the limit comparison test.

For the given example, take $a_n = 1/n$ and $b_n = 1/(2(n+1) - 1) = 1/(2n + 1)$ to get $2$ as the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing term by term, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k
&\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k-\frac12}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{k-\frac12}-\frac1{n+\frac12}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k+\frac12}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac1{k-\frac12}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{k-\frac12}-2
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
2\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{2k-1}-2\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le2\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{n+\frac12}
$$
and therefore,
$$
2-\frac2{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{2k-1}}\le\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{2k-1}}\le2-\frac1{\left(n+\frac12\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{2k-1}}
$$
Now apply the Squeeze Theorem.